# Select the category with the most entries in the database

Tags: php, mysql, count

i have got to the stage where i can display a count of how many entries are in each category. It echo's the data like this

```
There are 6 in the category number1
There are 4 in the category number2
There are 1 in the category number4
There are 1 in the category number5
There are 1 in the category number8
```

However all i want is it to show the most popular category. So for instance - the most popular categoryNo is "" with "" entries

Code:

```
- $count_query_v1 = "SELECT categoryNo, COUNT(entryNo)
FROM entries
GROUP by categoryNo;
";

$answer = mysql_query($count_query_v1) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($answer)){
echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(entryNo)'] ."in the category number". $row['categoryNo']    ." ;

}
```

How would i go about this?

Comment: Why don't you put all the counts in an array and use max() to return the highest values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "the most popular". If you mean the most popular category is a single category containing the most entries, then this would be your query:

```sql
SELECT categoryNo, COUNT(entryNo) as numEntries
FROM entries
GROUP by categoryNo
ORDER by numEntries DESC
LIMIT 1
```